# C# How to call the base class == operator, without explicitly typecasting?

Tags: c#, oop, operators, overriding

I have a base class (TFoo) and descendant class (TBar); I am overriding the == operator for both. I would like the descendant class to check its own fields and also call the base class's == operator so that the base class will do its own checks.

In the below code, you will see that within the `TBar == operator`, I typecast to the base class to check base class equality, like so: `(TFoo)a == (TFoo)b`.

(This appears to work! Hopefully there is not some gotcha that I have missed in my tests.)

However, I am looking for a more elegant way to do this. For example, `(base)a == (base)b` or `a base.== b` or `base.==(a, b)` or `a.base.Equals(b)` or something.

Obviously the above examples do not work and may look ridiculous; and as noted, `(TFoo)a == (TFoo)b` does work properly. I'm looking for a way to do this *without explicitly naming* the `TFoo` class.

***Edit: thanks for all the wonderful responses! I have modified the original code below, to compare `.GetType()` directly; I removed the `.Name` that several people have pointed out is dumb and dangerous.***

```
class TFoo
{
    public int foo;

    public static bool operator ==(TFoo a, TFoo b)
    {
        return a.GetType() == b.GetType()
            && a.foo == b.foo;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TFoo a, TFoo b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is TFoo) && this == (TFoo)obj;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.foo;
    }
}

class TBar : TFoo
{
    public int bar;

    public static bool operator ==(TBar a, TBar b)
    {
        return (TFoo)a == (TFoo)b
            && a.bar == b.bar;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(TBar a, TBar b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is TBar) && this == (TBar)obj;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just write `a.GetType() == b.GetType()` without `.Name` and `(obj as TFoo) == this`.

Comment: what about `a == b as TFoo`?

Comment: I cannot understand why you are checking to see if two types are equal by their reflected name. Why are you doing this strange, dangerous, wrong thing? If the intention is to say that the types must be identical then **why are you not comparing the types directly**?

Comment: Also, this is dangerous because it is not null-safe. We expect that `foo == null` should work, but in your implementation, it always crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing equality both correctly and elegantly in C# is unnecessarily hard; this is an area of the language which I strongly believe to have been under-designed.

My advice is:

First, fix your implementation. It is broken in many ways:

- `==` should never crash, but your implementation crashes immediately if `==` is given a `null` operand
- Types are *already* compared using value semantics; you should never compare two types for equality by their names! You can have two types from two different assemblies with the same name, or two types that are the same type from the same assembly loaded into different contexts!  Compare types by comparing types. If the intention is to say that `a` and `b` must be exactly the same type then say `a.GetType() == b.GetType()`, after you know that neither is null

Once you've fixed your implementation, improve it:

- Take cheap, easy outs when you can get them.  Always check for reference equality first, using `object.ReferenceEquals` to make it clear to the reader that this is what you are doing.
- Conversely: if you are checking for reference equality, call `object.ReferenceEquals` explicitly, and avoid many dumb bugs where you accidentally call `operator ==` when you meant to do reference equality.
- Write *one* method that is a *single source of truth* for equality for a given type, and then call that method -- directly or indirectly -- from all the other methods that implement equality.  Since your intention is to make the implementation of the derived class depend on the details of the base class, **make it a protected virtual method**.
- Since you're doing all this work anyways you might as well implement `IEquatable<T>` on your types while you're at it.

I would do something like this:

```
class Foo : IEquatable<Foo> 
{
  public override bool GetHashcode() { ... }
  protected virtual bool EqualsImplementation(Foo f) 
  {
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, f)) return true;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(f, null)) return false;
    ... We now have this and f as valid, not ref equal Foos.
    ... implement the comparison logic here
  }
  // Now implement Equals(object) by using EqualsImplementation():
  public bool Equals(object f) => 
    (!object.ReferenceEquals(f, null)) &&  
    (f.GetType() == this.GetType()) &&
    this.EqualsImplementation((Foo)f);
  // Now implement Equals(Foo) using Equals(object)
  public bool Equals(Foo f) => this.Equals((object)f);
  // Now implement Equals(Foo, Foo) using Equals(Foo)
  public static bool Equals(Foo f1, Foo f2) =>
    object.ReferenceEquals(f1, null) ? 
      object.ReferenceEquals(f2, null) :
      f1.Equals(f2);
  // You see how this goes. Every subsequent method uses
  // the correctness of the previous method to ensure its
  // correctness in turn!
  public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2) => 
    Equals(f1, f2);
  public static bool operator !=(Foo f1, Foo f2) => 
    !(f1 == f2);
  ...
}
```

And now everything is easy peasy in the derived class:

```
class Bar : Foo, IEquatable<Bar> 
{
  public override bool GetHashcode() { ... }
  protected override bool EqualsImplementation(Foo f) 
  {
    // Again, take easy outs when you find them.
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, f)) return true;
    Bar b = f as Bar;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(b, null)) return false;
    if (!base.EqualsImplementation(f)) return false;
    ... We have b and this, not ref equal, both Bars, both
    ... equal according to Foo.  Do the Bar logic here.
  }

  // Note that there is no need to override Equals(object). It
  // already has a correct implementation in Foo.

  // And once again we can use the correctness of the previous
  // method to implement the next method.  We need this method
  // to implement IEquatable<Bar>'s contract:

  public bool Equals(Bar b) => this.Equals((object)b);

  // As noted in a comment below, the following are not strictly
  // necessary, as the (Foo, Foo) methods in the base class do
  // the right thing when given two Bars.  However, it might be
  // nice for debugging or self-documenting-code reasons to implement
  // them, and they're easy.  Omit them if you like.

  public static bool Equals(Bar b1, Bar b2) =>
    object.ReferenceEquals(b1, null) ? 
      object.ReferenceEquals(b2, null) : 
      b1.Equals(b2);
  public static bool operator ==(Bar b1, Bar b2) => Equals(b1, b2);
  public static bool operator !=(Bar b1, Bar b2) => !(b1 == b2);
}
```

And we're done.  We have boilerplate implementations of `Equals(object)`, `Equals(T)`, `Equals(T, T)`, `==(T, T)` and `!=(T, T)` that can be simply cut-n-pasted when you need this pattern, and the type-specific details go into a type-specific virtual protected method, where they belong.

Comment: If you're ultimately calling the virtual `EqualsImplementation` method, and binary operators are inherited, is there any need to implement the `==` operator in the derived class, provided you have overloaded `EqualsImplementation`?

Comment: @JonathonChase: That's a great observation! I think it is nice for both debugging purposes and self-documenting purposes to implement them -- it sends a message to the consumer that comparing two Bars for equality is by-design -- but you are right to note that it is not strictly necessary. I'll add a note to the code.

Comment: A mistake I made while playing around with this was not making sure that every possible path was checking for type equality between the operands. You have this covered with everything going through the `Foo.Equals(Object)` method at some point, but failing to cover that case can definitely lead to oddness like `(SomeFoo == SomeBar) != (SomeBar == SomeFoo)` being true. I suppose that just comes with the territory, but it's a potentially nasty mistake.

Comment: @JonathonChase: Right, this whole area is nothing but pitfalls. That's why I consider this to be a design failure. We want C# to be a "pit of success" language, where the right way and the easy way are the same. Equality definitely does not have that property!  The problem has many roots, but a big one is that equality is defined both as a single dispatch virtual method *and* a static dispatch method, when what we want is a double dispatch virtual method *which as you note must maintain symmetry*. That concept just doesn't exist in the runtime.

Comment: "You can have two types from two different assemblies with the same name" — Immediate flashbacks of Delphi's "Instance of 'TBitmap' is not an instance of 'TBitmap' class" messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply override `Equals` in `TFoo` and call it from `==`, and then override it again in `TBar`. Then, you just call `base.Equals` from `TBar.Equals` for check the base properties

It will simplify the logic I think

```
class TFoo
{
    public int foo;

    public static bool operator ==(TFoo a, TFoo b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }  

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.GetType() == obj.GetType()
            && this.foo == ((TFoo)obj).foo;
    }

    //your code
}


class TBar : TFoo
{
    public int bar;

    public static bool operator ==(TBar a, TBar b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is TBar) && this.bar == ((TBar)obj).bar && base.Equals(obj);
    }

    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you must do the casting `(TFoo)a == (TFoo)b` is that the `==` operator is static. I.e., the runtime type is not considered, instead the `==` operator of the static type known at compile-time will be used, if you don't' cast. In contrast, `Equals` is an instance member whose implementation is determined at runtime by the actual type of the caller object. If you want a dynamic behavior, base your `==` operator on `Equals`.

We expect the `==` operator to be symmetric. I.e., `a == b` should be the same as `b == a`. But we do not necessarily expect `a.Equals(b)` to be the same a `b.Equals(a)`, since if `a` and `b` have different types, then different implementations of `Equals` will be called. Therefore, I suggest implementing the `==` operator by calling `a.Equals(b) && b.Equals(a)` (and to handle nulls).

```
class Foo
{
    public int foo;

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return other is Foo otherFoo && foo.Equals(otherFoo.foo);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo first, Foo second)
    {
        if ((object)first == null) {
            return (object)second == null;
        }
        return first.Equals(second) && second.Equals(first);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo first, Foo second)
    {
        return !(first == second);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            return foo.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

And the derived class

```
class Bar : Foo
{
    public int bar;

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return other is Bar otherBar && bar.Equals(otherBar.bar) && base.Equals(other);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Bar first, Bar second)
    {
        if ((object)first == null) {
            return (object)second == null;
        }
        return first.Equals(second) && second.Equals(first); // In case one is more derived.
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Bar first, Bar second)
    {
        return !(first == second);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked {
            return (base.GetHashCode() * 53) ^ bar.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```